# $g'(t)=\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}(x(t),t)+ (u(x,t).\nabla)\rho(x,t)$.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, chain-rule, fluid-dynamics

We are **Studying the behavior of the fluid using Navier Stokes' Equation**, and I am new to this lesson, but I am stuck on my below question:

If I have $g(t)=\rho(x(t),t)$, then using **Chain rule**, we get:
$$g'(t)=\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}(x(t),t)+\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x}(x(t),t)x'(t)$$

So how to continue in order to get the latter is equal to : $$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}(x(t),t)+ (u(x,t).\nabla)\rho(x,t).$$

Remark that $u(x,t)=x'(t)$ is the **velocity field of the flow of the fluid** (here we are dealing with the Eulerian description), and $\rho:\Omega×[0,T] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is the **mass density**, $\nabla$ is the **nabla function**

I am really stuck and I need some help please!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that $x(t)=(x_1(t),x_2(t),x_3(t))$ and $u(t,x)=(x'_1(t),x'_2(t),x'_3(t))$
by the chain rules results

$$g'(t)=\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}(x(t),t)+\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x_1}(x(t),t)x_1'(t)+\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x_2}(x(t),t)x_2'(t)+\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x_3}(x(t),t)x_3'(t)$$

$$g'(t)=\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}(x(t),t)+(x'_1(t),x'_2(t),x'_3(t)) \cdot 
\left(\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x_1}(x(t),t),\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x_2}(x(t),t),\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x_3}(x(t),t)\right )  $$

$$g'(t)=\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}(x(t),t)+ u(x,t) \cdot 
\left(\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x_1}(x(t),t),\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x_2}(x(t),t),\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x_3}(x(t),t)\right )$$

$$g'(t)=\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}(x(t),t)+ u(x,t) \cdot \nabla \rho(x(t),t).
$$

Comment: thank you, you've got my point, but still have a problem: how did we separate $u(x,t)(\nabla\rho(x,t))$ to get $(u(x,t).\nabla)\rho(x,t)$!

Comment: Yes the notation is a little bit confusing but It's the same thing observe that the operator expansion 
$u(x,t) \cdot \nabla = (u_1(x,t),u_2(x,t),u_3(x,t)) \cdot (\partial_{x_1}(\cdot),\partial_{x_2}(\cdot),\partial_{x_3}(\cdot)) = u_1(x,t)\partial_{x_1}(\cdot) +u_2(x,t)\partial_{x_2}(\cdot)+u_3(x,t)\partial_{x_3}(\cdot)$  Then
$(u(x,t)\cdot \nabla)\rho(x,t) =u_1(x,t)\partial_{x_1}\rho + u_2(x,t)\partial_{x_2}\rho+u_3(x,t)\partial_{x_3}\rho = u(x,t)\cdot (\nabla \rho)$

Comment: thank you it really helped!